# ArrayList with JSON

Tags: json

I want to get the following json format in java.

```
{ 
  { 
    "categoryname": Veg thali
  }
  { 
    "categoryname": Non Veg Thali
  }

}
```

This will be the output what I need by `json` object.
I have written code as:

```
public static JSONObject selectCategoryName() throws Exception 
{
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        JSONObject categoryNameList =  new JSONObject();
        ArrayList<String> catList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String sqlQuery = "select category_name from food_category";
        try {

            connection = DBConnection.createConnection();
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while(resultSet.next()){
                catList.add(resultSet.getString("category_name"));

            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
        categoryNameList.put("\"category Name\"", catList);
        return categoryNameList;
    }
```

And the output of my above code is given as::

```
 {
      -"category Name": [2]
        0:  "Veg thali"
        1:  "Non Veg Thali"
    }
```

**Please help me how can get my required `json` object format?**

Comment: Neither your output nor your *required* output are valid JSON.

Comment: You please tell me the valid JSON plzz plzz..

Comment: Google: *JSON format*. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First up, your desired JSON isn't valid.

This would be valid:

```
{ 
  "categories": [{"categoryname": "Veg thali"}, {"categoryname": "Non Veg Thali"}] 
}
```

If you don't want an array, then you can't use a list in the object you're serializing, because you need name-value pairs.

```
{
  "category1": {"categoryname": "Veg thali"},
  "category2": {"categoryname": "Non Veg thali"},
  // and so on
}
```

But this doesn't work well, because you don't know how many rows you're getting back from the database.  Therefore, your JSON will have an indeterminate form.

You can achieve this by getting rid of the ArrayList and doing something like this in the loop: (this is pseudocode)

```
int counter = 0;
while(resultSet.next()) {
    JSONObject tempObj =  new JSONObject();
    tempObj.put("categoryname", resultSet.getString("category_name"));
    categoryNameList.put("category" + ++i, tempObj);
}
```

...but the resulting object will be a horrible indeterminate mess.

**TL;DR** if you want to represent a list in JSON, use an array.

Comment: Thanks for response first. Ok i need the format as,                                     { 
     "categories":  [                                                                           {"categoryname": "Veg thali"},                                            {"categoryname": "Non Veg Thali"}                                                                 ]                                                                                                                             
}

Comment: It's the format you already have.  I suspect your JSON viewer is formatting the array in that way. There are various JSON viewers available for web browsers, or you can save the JSON and view it in a text editor.

Comment: I have made some changes in the code as;                                                        while(resultSet.next()){
    JSONObject jobject =  new JSONObject();
       jobject.put("\"categoryname\"",resultSet.getString("category_name"));
       jArray.put(jobject);//jArray is json array
   }
     categoryNameList.put("Categories:", jArray);//categoryNameList is json object
     return categoryNameList;
    }

Comment: You didn't need to make any changes. I suggest you revert back to your original code and find a different JSON viewer.

Comment: out put is:{
-Categories:: [2]
-0:  {
"categoryname": "Veg thali"
}
-1:  {
"categoryname": "Non VegThali"
}
}

Comment: That's not valid JSON.  What are you using to view it?

Comment: google chrome extension Advanced rest client application

Comment: That's reformatting the JSON.  Look at the raw response and you'll see the underlying JSON.

Comment: Thank u very much ..I got my result. Thanks Thanks a lot of thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public static JSONObject selectCategoryName() throws Exception {

        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject categoryNameList =  new JSONObject();

        String sqlQuery = "select category_name from food_category";
        try {

            connection = DBConnection.createConnection();

            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while(resultSet.next()){
                JSONObject jobject =  new JSONObject();
                jobject.put("categoryname",resultSet.getString("category_name"));
                jArray.put(jobject);
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }

        categoryNameList.put("Categories:", jArray);
        return categoryNameList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a JsonNodeFactory:

**final JsonNodeFactory factory = JsonNodeFactory.instance;**

This class has methods to create ArrayNodes.